# DB2 function to convert a string to integer?

Tags: string, integer, db2

I have a table which stores database details like `Database_Name`,`Database_status` etc.Under `Database_status` column,the entries are "`Active`" and "`Inactive`".Here I want to convert the string "`Active`" to '`1`' and "`Inactive`" to '`0`'

Comment: Are you seeking to replace values in the table? Or do you simply want to translate from one set of values to another set when using this table for some purpose? What is it you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

`update T
     set Database_status = case Database_status when 'Active' then '1'
                                                when 'Inactive' then '0'
                           end
 where Database_status in ('Active','Inactive')`